# How to get the URL of the captured image?

Tags: java, android

I launch an activity to capture a picture from camera:

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE, null);
i.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(i, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
```

Can you please tell me how to get the URI of the capture picture ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the image that was just taken from the camera you would do the following

```
// Call to take the picture
startActivityForResult(new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE"), PICK_FROM_CAMERA);

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_CAMERA)
    {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
            // set the imageview image via uri 
            _previewImage.setImageURI(uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this on my Android 2.2 phone and `data.getData()` returns null.

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to Android, but I believe you have to add some extra information to the Intent.
The ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE documentation says:

> The caller may pass an extra EXTRA_OUTPUT to control where this image will be written. If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present, then a small sized image is returned as a Bitmap object in the extra field. This is useful for applications that only need a small image. If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is present, then the full-sized image will be written to the Uri value of EXTRA_OUTPUT.

So, I think you should be able to add in this line:

> intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File ("MyImageCapture")));

And then you should be able to get it from the URI in the onActivityResult.

But I haven't tested this. Hope I haven't lead you astray.

Comment: I have tried this: 

i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File ("MyImageCapture")) );
i.putExtra("outputFormat",    Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG.name());
           
        
startActivityForResult(i, PICK_ICON_FROM_CAMERA_ID);

But my onActivityResult() was never get called. Can you please tell me any idea for that happened?