# Android: Crop an Image after Taking it With Camera with a Fixed Aspect Ratio

Tags: android

I'm trying to crop an image after taking it, and my code is as follows:

```
   private void doTakePhotoAction() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());
        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 96);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 96);

        try {
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            //Do nothing for now
        }
    }
```

With the above code, I'm able to go to crop mode, and crop the picture. However, the 1:1 aspect ratio is not enforced, and neither is the outputX and outputY. I believe this is because the intent was for taking a picture, not for cropping. I've also written another method to getData() from the Intent, and after that use the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
intent.setClassName("com.android.camera", "com.android.camera.CropImage");
```

However, when I do that, I get the following runtime error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(14648): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.camera/com.android.camera.CropImage}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 22):

After doing some reading, I realized it can't be done so simply. My modded Contacts source is at http://github.com/Wysie, you can take a look if you're interested. Also, here's what I did to get it working:

```
private void doTakePhotoAction() {
    // http://2009.hfoss.org/Tutorial:Camera_and_Gallery_Demo
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050297/how-to-get-the-url-of-the-captured-image
    // http://www.damonkohler.com/2009/02/android-recipes.html
    // http://www.firstclown.us/tag/android/
    // The one I used to get everything working: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/2ab62c12ee99ba30 

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    //Wysie_Soh: Create path for temp file
    mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        "tmp_contact_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"));

    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);

    try {
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        //Do nothing for now
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }

    switch (requestCode) {

    case CROP_FROM_CAMERA: {
        //Wysie_Soh: After a picture is taken, it will go to PICK_FROM_CAMERA, which will then come here
        //after the image is cropped.

        final Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

        if (extras != null) {
            Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");

            mPhoto = photo;
            mPhotoChanged = true;
            mPhotoImageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            setPhotoPresent(true);
        }

        //Wysie_Soh: Delete the temporary file                        
        File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());            
        if (f.exists()) {
            f.delete();
        }

        InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        mgr.showSoftInput(mPhotoImageView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

        break;
    }

    case PICK_FROM_CAMERA: {
        //Wysie_Soh: After an image is taken and saved to the location of mImageCaptureUri, come here
        //and load the crop editor, with the necessary parameters (96x96, 1:1 ratio)

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        intent.setClassName("com.android.camera", "com.android.camera.CropImage");

        intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 96);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 96);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);            
        startActivityForResult(intent, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);

        break;

    }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks Wysie, but it not work in android 2.x. This is the exception:

04-29 18:35:02.857: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3486): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.camera/com.android.camera.CropImage}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: if outputX is more then 500 so not working any idea?

Comment: Great code! Thank you for that. If you have the error from @NguyenMinhBinh look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21879630/crop-image-on-different-devices)

Comment: it returns null in onactivityresult

Answer (score 3):

Check out this post. I tested it on my android 1.5 (Htc Magic) and worked perfectly.

[Android Works](http://www.androidworks.com/crop_large_photos_with_android)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this `Intent` (but keeping the crop/aspect/output/return-data extras you already have)?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
```

That's basically what the [Android contacts application](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/contacts/EditContactActivity.java;h=b89573b70fd594f5796083c6a0e4312caca3a58d;hb=donut#l692) does, so perhaps it won't quite fit your use case (i.e. taking a photo immediately, rather than having the option of selecting one from the gallery *or* taking a new photo).

Worth a try anyway! :)

Comment: Does not work either for me: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT (has extras) }

Answer (score -3):

Though this might be a very old thread, I was able to crop a picture programmatically with the following code :

```
        btnTakePicture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });
```

then I cropped it with :

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

        performcrop();
    }

}

private void performcrop() {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

    Bitmap croppedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(photo, 0, 0, width / 2,
            photo.getHeight());

    imageTaken.setImageBitmap(croppedBmp);
}
```

imageTaken is an ImageView Component in my view. You can see my source [Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e5156/how-to-capture-and-crop-image-in-android-studio/)