# Permission errors when cropping after taking a photo

Tags: android

I want to take a photo with an Intent on android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE,

next crop the result with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
intent.setClassName("com.android.camera", "com.android.camera.CropImage");
```

I follow the sugestions made at:
[Android: Crop an Image after Taking it With Camera with a Fixed Aspect Ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973359/android-crop-an-image-after-taking-it-with-camera-with-a-fixed-aspect-ratio)

However when calling the crop activity I get (already checked the LogCat output) a permission error, saying something like:

Permission denial on a Intent to access the temporary image created by the camera activity on my SDcard.

Can you please suggest a solution for Android 2.2 ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

CGM,

DO you have

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

It would be required to modify something on the SD Card.

Comment: Hi Willytale, I have the following permissions set in the AndroidManifest.xml:<uses-permission android:name="android.permisson.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_OWNER_DATA" />

Comment: Hmm, based on your description you shouldn't need any others.  Could you post the exact error from logcat?

Comment: Permission Denial: starting Intent {act=com.android.camera.action.CROP dat=file///sdcard/tmp_contact_1297269884838.jpg...}

Comment: It seems the crop intent was actually removed from froyo.  See: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/2dd647523926192c/167af114c229c489?lnk=raot

Answer (score -1):

Searching the SDK finds no mention of ["com.android.camera.action.CROP"](http://developer.android.com/search.html#q=com.android.camera.action.CROP&t=0). As such it is an undocumented implementation detail of the system and, if not broken already, is likely to break in the future.

willytate posted this informative link in the comments. I'll repost: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/2dd647523926192c/167af114c229c489?lnk=raot&pli=1

Dianne Hackborn is the authority on the matter.