# Android Camera - Can we take a part of an image from the full screen

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview, preview

I want to take an particular part of an image from the image preview. Is it possible, if so how to do that?

for ex, [image]

I just want to show some limit to the user, so they can take partial part of an image. How to show my surface view like the given above picture and how to take particular part of an image??

Thanks is in advance.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973359/android-crop-an-image-after-taking-it-with-camera-with-a-fixed-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any way to capture less than the full preview.  You could display the crop marks as an overlay, and retrieve that portion of the bitmap in post-processing after you capture the image.