# Crop an image when selected from gallery in android

Tags: android

I want to crop an image in my application when it is selected from gallery.
i.e if I launch the gallery and select an image the cropping window should come like when we select an image from iPhone. Is it possible in Android.

I found one tutorial for cropping the image in android, but dont seem the way I wanted.

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/03/15/crop-an-image-in-android/

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085003/how-to-select-and-crop-an-image-in-android) i hope it will help you.

Comment: see my answer hope that's what you are looking for, if you find some problem or you don't understand the code, let me know

Comment: I have posted my solution [here] on stackoverflow post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44089387/1448357)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes it's possible to crop image in android by using `com.android.camera.action.CROP`. after picking image url from gallery.you will start Crop Editor as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");  
intent.setClassName("com.android.camera", "com.android.camera.CropImage");  
File file = new File(filePath);  
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);  
intent.setData(uri);  
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");  
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);  
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);  
intent.putExtra("outputX", 96);  
intent.putExtra("outputY", 96);  
intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);  
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);                                  
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CROP_ICON);
```

When the picture select Activity return will be selected to save the contents.in `onActivityResult`:

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();  
if(extras != null ) {  
    Bitmap photo = extras.getParcelable("data");  
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, stream);  
        // The stream to write to a file or directly using the photo
}
```

and see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973359/android-crop-an-image-after-taking-it-with-camera-with-a-fixed-aspect-ratio) which is also help you for cropping image in android

Comment: The `com.android.camera.action.CROP` action is part of the Internal API and thus won't work in all cases. Just wanted to mention that :)

Comment: In which cases isn't it gonna work ? When manufacturer has a legacy layer ?

Comment: This will not work on many, many devices. Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Comment: how do i set minimum scale value ? For i.e. I want user to keep width and height at least of 300*300.

Comment: In my case, `data.getExtras()` returns a `Bundle` of `null`, then how could I get the target `Bitmap`?

Comment: Doesn't work in 5.0+ with Photos app (Gallery was removed in Nexus devices after 5.0)

Comment: @AlexLockwood then what to use to do croping? and also `com.android.camera.action.CROP` works perfect in all device , only in lenovo  not worked. it display toast that can't edit image under 50x50 ! what sholud to do?

Comment: @Dharmishtha Use a library or implement it yourself. Like I said, the intent is part of an internal API, so it is not guaranteed to work and it is not guaranteed to continue to work in the future.

Comment: ok@AlexLockwood i have used library for cropping . the library is [Yalantis 
 uCrop](https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop) .And it works perfect.

Comment: What does `putExtra("return-data", true)` do?

Answer (score 21):

This [tutorial](http://www.londatiga.net/featured-articles/how-to-select-and-crop-image-on-android/) is exactly what you need enjoy:

Picking image from gallery:

[image]

Crop image after Intent pick action

[image]

Cheers

Comment: This worked like a charm , perfect answer and very easy to use.

Comment: @K_Anas the tutorial which you have described here is not working for API>19. It shows an error of : Failed to load image. Please help me out here

Comment: this is not a good solution as it will not work on many devices as the Intent is not part of Android.

Answer (score 17):

You can already tell the Camera/Gallery-Intent to start the crop-editor after the image is selected/taken:

### Pick Image from Gallery:

```
Intent pickImageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

pickImageIntent.setType("image/*");
pickImageIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
pickImageIntent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
pickImageIntent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
pickImageIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
pickImageIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
pickImageIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
pickImageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriWhereToStore);
pickImageIntent.putExtra("outputFormat",

Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
startActivityForResult(pickImageIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

### Take Photo:

```
Intent takePicIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

takePicIntent .putExtra("crop", "true");
takePicIntent .putExtra("outputX", 200);
takePicIntent .putExtra("outputY", 200);
takePicIntent .putExtra("aspectX", 1);
takePicIntent .putExtra("aspectY", 1);
takePicIntent .putExtra("scale", true);
takePicIntent .putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriWhereToStore);
takePicIntent .putExtra("outputFormat",

Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
startActivityForResult(takePicIntent , RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

Comment: Then how to do `onActivityResult()` corresponding to your codes?

Comment: @AliParsa How to get the cropped image in `onActivityResult()` ?

Comment: Working only for ACTION_PICK not for IMAGE_CAPTURE

Comment: This solutions is working for only ACTION_PICK and not IMAGE_CAPTURE, what should be done for IMAGE_CAPTURE?

Answer (score 15):

Although part of the internal API, the `com.android.camera.action.CROP` seems like it is well-supported on most Android devices. This might get you started:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
intent.setData(uriOfImageToCrop);
intent.putExtra("outputX", 400);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 400);
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
intent.putExtra("scale", true);
intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
intent.putExtra("output", Uri.fromFile(someOutputFile));
startActivityForResult(intent, SOME_RANDOM_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Then handle what you need to do in the `onActivityResult()` method of your `Activity`. Your output file should be the cropped image.

Since this `Intent` action is part of the internal API, however, I would **strongly advise** that you have some sort of fallback behavior if some device does not support the `Intent`. Some manufacturers provide their own Gallery apps and so there is no way of knowing whether or not the user's device will recognize the `Intent`. **PLEASE DON'T FORGET THIS!!** :)

Comment: The thing I was looking was intent.putExtra("output", Uri.fromFile(someOutputFile));

Comment: Can you say how can I print the cropped (outputX,outputY...) values in logcat

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem this way

```
private void pickUserImage() { 

if (doHavePermission()) { 
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getTempUri());
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
    } 
}
```

find my complete solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44193985/1448357) in stackoverflow post

Answer (score 0):

Nobody will tell you which extra is needed unless you try it:

```
   val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
   intent.apply {
       type = "image/*"
       putExtra("crop", "true") // NOTE: should be string
       putExtra("outputX", 300) // This is needed, editor can't close without these two
       putExtra("outputY", 300) // This is needed

       putExtra("scale", true)
       putExtra("aspectX", 1)
       putExtra("aspectY", 1)
       putExtra("return-data", true)
   }
   startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_INT_CODE)
```

Comment: It does not work for me. Do you have anything special inside onActivityResult() ?

Comment: What is `putExtra("return-data", true)` doing?