# Android crop photo from camera

Tags: android

i want crop photo that i take from camera, so far i try do it like this but with no success

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File f = new File(android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));

                intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
                intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);

                getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

is it possible to do it without any 3th part libraries.?
i checked https://github.com/biokys/cropimage

but it doesnt gave me any results

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            String path = data.getStringExtra(CropImage.IMAGE_PATH);

            // if nothing received
            if (path == null) {

                return;
            }

            // cropped bitmap
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);

            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userpicture)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776438/crop-an-image-when-selected-from-gallery-in-android

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to do it without any 3th part libraries.?

Not reliably. [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html).

> i checked https://github.com/biokys/cropimage but it doesnt gave me any results

Perhaps you did not integrate it properly. In addition to the libraries mentioned in my blog post (linked to above), [the Android Arsenal has a few options](http://android-arsenal.com/search?q=crop).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private void performCrop(Uri picUri) {
        try {

            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            // indicate image type and Uri
            cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
            // set crop properties
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            // indicate aspect of desired crop
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            // indicate output X and Y
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 128);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 128);
            // retrieve data on return
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
        }
        // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            // display an error message
            String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

declare:

```
final int PIC_CROP = 1;
```

at top.

In onActivity result method, writ following code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PIC_CROP) {
        if (data != null) {
            // get the returned data
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            // get the cropped bitmap
            Bitmap selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");

            imgView.setImageBitmap(selectedBitmap);
        }
    }

}
```