# Draggable Bitmap In Fix Frame In Android

Tags: java, android

I want to create an android app that has a fix frame and a draggable bitmap in it. Actually I want something like facebook cover reposition! How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `crop`
see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973359/android-crop-an-image-after-taking-it-with-camera-with-a-fixed-aspect-ratio) to learn how to implement the `crop`
By using this you can fix the aspect ratio of your frame if you want, and the image is draggable in the frame as you want.