# Android camera preview with fixed bounding box

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I want to take a picture of a rectangle shaped object. If the camera preview have a bounding rectangle i can take the picture by placing the object inside the bounding box. I need only that specified(inside the box) area of the image.Now I have developed a Camera App(Using **Camera API** Not INTENT) which can take pictures and store the pic like the inbuilt camera App.
 How to draw a rectangle on the camera preview? and how to crop before saving?
I am using android 2.2

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.
What have you done so far?

Comment: developed a camera App Using camera API which can take pictures and store. thats all. Thank u for your reply

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add an camera overlay to achieve this. Take a look at the Samples at `samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview`. You can have your own layout over the preview area and add your graphic to it.

Check: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/12/add-overlay-on-camera-preview.html
and [Android: Crop an Image after Taking it With Camera with a Fixed Aspect Ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973359/android-crop-an-image-after-taking-it-with-camera-with-a-fixed-aspect-ratio) for more samples.

Comment: A layer/layout over the camera preview. I can't believe you developed a camera app without knowing overlays.

Comment: heyy.. i just need to draw a rectangle on camera preview that is wot i asked

Comment: Please refer the links. It contains examples for achieving what you need.

Comment: I got a file from http://adblogcat.com/a-camera-preview-with-a-bounding-box-like-google-goggles/ here but it contains errors in the xml file.. could you please correct this @Rlhan .:)

Comment: It contains a class named TouchView.java and the error on xml file is TouchView failed to instantiate.. i ve tried restartind eclipse and did building and cleaning but it still have the same error

Comment: I just downloaded and ran the code. its working without any errors. Check if you have all the project files and try again.

Comment: Could you please mail me that complete zip file please.??