# Output size of image crop

Tags: android, crop

I use following code to crop an image from gallery:

```
             intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
//          intent.putExtra("scale", true);

            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 4);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 3);
            intent.putExtra("outputX", 400);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", 300);

            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
```

The ratio is fine. But the croped images have bad quality. I have looked into the size and they are not 400x300 but 185x139 size. 
I have googled a lot but cannot find the issue. Can someone give a hint?

I am testing on a Samsung S3 device. It seems that there is a maximum of the output size.
Can I somehow circumvent it?

Comment: Have you checked this post? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1973359/558991

Comment: I read it, but I dont see how this solves my problem.