# How can I crop image view after get from custom camera

Tags: android, image, android-camera, crop

I am using custom camera, now i setting image to a imageview which is got from custom camera. now I want to crop that image on 4:3 ratio. how can I do this(I have tried to using third party library but its using default camera or gallery)? Plase help..

Comment: this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973359/android-crop-an-image-after-taking-it-with-camera-with-a-fixed-aspect-ratio/1976115#1976115

Comment: but it is using default camera. i am using custom camera

Comment: the main part is when the image is taked in case PICK_FROM_CAMERA...@Wysie call "com.android.camera.CropImage" setting aspect ratio, here is the trick, you have an image taked from your custom camera , saved in your local storage call then com.android.camera.CropImage.

Comment: if you have any dude, post your onActivityResult to make an answer